# Non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame

Tags: r

In the code below I select `DR` columns that are equal to zero.

```
r <- data.frame(DR01 = 3, DR02 = 4, DR03 = 0, DR04 = 0) 

names(rev(r)[, cumsum(rev(r)) == 0])

[1] "DR04" "DR03
```

However, I have a new database with more information, but when I do this: `names(rev(r)[, cumsum(rev(r)) == 0])` gives an error.

So how to tweak the code to fix this error? I believe I need to select only `DR` columns, am I correct?

```
r <- data.frame(date1= "2021-06-28",date2="2021-06-28",Category="ABC", DR01 = 3, DR02 = 4, DR03 = 0, DR04 = 0) 

names(rev(r)[, cumsum(rev(r)) == 0])

Error in Math.data.frame(rev(r)) : 
  non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: Category, date2, date1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to select all `numeric` columns before having arithmetic operation on them.

> I believe I need to select only DR columns, am I correct?

Yes if you only want to select names that start with `DR` and if all `DR` columns are numeric.

#### Base R

```
names(which(colSums(df[,sapply(df, is.numeric)]) == 0))
```

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

colnames(df %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% select(which(colSums(.) == 0)))
```